# Error Displaying Facebook Social Plugins

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

Im having problems using the Facebook social plugins. If its important, I use GWT to display the code inside an HTML widjet

I put this in my html

```
<script>
(function(d, s, id) 
{     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if    (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}    
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;      
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";  
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);   
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));   
</script>   
<fb:comments width="600" num_posts="2" href="http://www.woojah.com"></fb:comments>
```

And nothing is displayed. However, if I open the source code with firebug, and I cut that code and paste it again, it is displayed. It is as if that code needs a special "refreshing" or "reloading". By the way, I got that code from the developers.facebook.com page. It's the social plugin comment code.

Also my html tag is `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">`

So my question is: Does anyone know why the comment plugin is not displayed and why, when I cut and paste the exact same code with firebug it is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using the FB.XFBML.parse() command to have the SDK reparse the page after you use GWT to insert the code inside your widget.